# VSO/TFS - copy file under a new name as part of build process

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops

I need to copy an existing file under a new name in the build process so I can then do something with this new file. I did not find any (working) Task for this very basic functionality.

This does notwork anymore: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=delegen.DelegenCopy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Command Line` task.

`Tool: "copy"`, `Arguments: "originalfile.txt newfile.txt /Y"` where `/Y` is for automatic file override(if exists).